# Scroll horizontally with UIScrollView don't seems to work with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a Horizontal Scroll using `UIScrollView` and a `UIImageView`. The image View has a width of 1280px (4 pages) and the scrollView 320px. When I use this code WITHOUT autolayout mode, the scroll works properly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    CGRect imageFrame = self.helpImageView.frame;
    NSLog(@"imageFrame w: %f",self.helpImageView.frame.size.width); //prints 1280.000000
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:imageFrame.size];
    NSLog(@"contentSize w: %f",self.scrollView.contentSize.width); //prints 1280.0000
    NSLog(@"scrollFrame w: %f",self.scrollView.frame.size.width); //prints 320.00
}
```

But, if I want to use Autolayout, this code returns the same result but the `UIScrollView` does not scroll. Why??? I'm using these constraits:

```
Bottom space to: ScrollView Equals:32.0
Leading space to: ScrollView
Trailing space to: ScrollView
Top Space To: SCrollView Equals:-20.0
Bottom Space To: View Equals:-12.0
Leading space to: View
Top Space To: View Equals:427.0
Trailing space to: View
```

Answer (score 0):

I also created horizontal scroll view, then initial values are as follows.

CustomScrollView.m :

```
self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.scrollsToTop = NO;
self.delegate = (id)self;
self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0 * PAGE_COUNT, 420.0);
self.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.bounces = NO;

for (int i = 0; i < PAGE_COUNT; i++) {
//  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", @"foo", i, @".png"];
    UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str]];
//  imgView.frame = CGRectMake(320.0f * i + 10, 0, 300, 300 * 1.33);
    [self addSubview:imgView];
}
```

In this project, PAGE_COUNT=4 and 4 images are foo0.png ~ foo3.png.